# Create conditional Column in dataframes based on 3 other column values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a dataframe like this:

```
    RING    CLLI      CIRCUIT       SITE
0   N100    M200      Circuit1      M200
1   N100    M200      Circuit2      M200
2   N100    M201      Circuit3      M201
3   N101    M200 23   Circuit1      M200
4   N101    M300      Circuit1      M300
5   N101    M304 XK   Circuit11     M304
6   N101    M147      Circuit10     M147
7   N102    M304E5    Circuit11     M304
8   N102    M874      Circuit114    M874
9   N102    M874      Circuit113    M874
10  N102    M874      Circuit112    M874
11  N104    M643      Circuit2      M643
12  N104    M643      Circuit234    M643
13  N104    M304      Circuit11     M304
```

I want to add a conditional Column (NeigbourCLLI) based on the values from the other columns. Basically what I want is to check:

```
1. Check if the Circuit from CIRCUIT column is the same
    a) If yes, check if the value from RING column is different
        1. If yes, check if the SITES column are a match
            a) If yes, add this to NeigbourCLLI (with comma separated if there are more
```

For Example, Circuit1 is present in row 1, 4, and 5. And This condition are met only in case of row 1 and 5. Meaning that for row 1 and 5 Circuit is the same, Ring is different and Sites are equal.
For Circuit11 which is present in row 6, 8 and 14. The condition is met in all of them and so on... And the final dataframe would look like this:

```
    RING    CLLI      CIRCUIT       SITE      NeigbourCLLI
0   N100    M200      Circuit1      M200        M200 23         # This one is taken from row    N101    M200 23   Circuit1      M200        NaN
1   N100    M200      Circuit2      M200        NaN
2   N100    M201      Circuit3      M201        NaN
3   N101    M200 23   Circuit1      M200        M200            # This one is taken from row    N100    M200      Circuit1      M200        M200 
4   N101    M300      Circuit1      M300        NaN
5   N101    M304 XK   Circuit11     M304        M304E5, M304    # This one is taken from row N102    M304E5    Circuit11     M304  and   N104    M304      Circuit11     M304
6   N101    M147      Circuit10     M147        NaN
7   N102    M304E5    Circuit11     M304        M304 XK, M304   # This one is taken from row N102    N101    M304 XK   Circuit11     M304  and  N104    M304      Circuit11     M304
8   N102    M874      Circuit114    M874        NaN       
9   N102    M874      Circuit113    M874        NaN
10  N102    M874      Circuit112    M874        NaN
11  N104    M643      Circuit2      M643        NaN
12  N104    M643      Circuit234    M643        NaN
13  N104    M304      Circuit11     M304        M304 XK, M304E5 # This one is taken from row N102    N101    M304 XK   Circuit11     M304  and  NN102    M304E5    Circuit11     M304
```

I have tried something like this, but is not very efficient in case of datafarme with more than 500k rows:

```
grouped = df.groupby('CIRCUIT').apply(lambda x: x['RING'].nunique() > 1)

def find_neighboring_cllis(row):
    circuit, ring, site = row['CIRCUIT'], row['RING'], row['site']
    if grouped[circuit]:
        neighbors = df[(df['CIRCUIT'] == circuit) & (df['RING'] != ring) & (df['SITE'] == site]['CLLI'].unique()
        if neighbors.size > 0:
            return ', '.join(neighbors)
    return np.nan

df['NeigbourCLLI'] = df.apply(find_neighboring_cllis, axis=1)
```

Is there a more "pandas" way to handle this?

Comment: Is it possible to have 2 rows with same CIRCUIT, SITE and RING values? And another row with same CIRCUIT and SITE than 2 previous rows but a different RING. What should be the output in this case for these rows A, A' and B?

Comment: Hi @Corralien, yes, that is possible as well, maybe I didn't include this scenario in my sample df, but this is present as well in my real dataframe. Thanks

Comment: Well. I updated my comment above, can you check it please?

Comment: So, your first question, If there are two rows with same CIRCUIT, SITE and RING, ignore it. If there are two other rows, with same CIRCUIT and SITE but different RING, add CLLI to NeigbourCLLI

Comment: @Corralien Please let me know if i answered your questions

Comment: Almost :). What is the expected output for this sample: `df = pd.DataFrame({'RING': ['N100', 'N101', 'N101'], 'CLLI': ['M200', 'M200 23', 'M300'], 'CIRCUIT': ['Circuit1', 'Circuit1', 'Circuit1'], 'SITE': ['M200', 'M200', 'M200']})`?

Comment: @Corralien This is somehow invalid in sense that SITES and CLLI are somehow related. What i Mean is that SITES is extracted from CLLI but in a shorter version, like first 4 letters.
But if we would have M200 instead of M300 in row 3
The final df would be: df1 = pd.DataFrame({'RING': ['N100', 'N101', 'N101'], 'CLLI': ['M200', 'M200 23', 'M200'], 'CIRCUIT': ['Circuit1', 'Circuit1', 'Circuit1'], 'SITE': ['M200', 'M200', 'M200'], 'NeighbourCLLI': ['M200 23, M200', 'M200', 'M200']})

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254254/discussion-between-user14073111-and-corralien).

Answer (score 2):

#### NEW VERSION

```py
def fn(x):
    out = []
    for r in x.RING:
        out.append(", ".join(x.loc[x.RING != r, "CLLI"]) or np.nan)
    x["NeigbourCLLI"] = out
    return x

df = df.groupby(["CIRCUIT", "SITE"], group_keys=False).apply(fn)
print(df)
```

---

#### OLD VERSION

You can try to apply `.pivot_table` inside `.groupby` to speed things up:

```py
def fn(x):
    out, z = [], x.pivot_table(
        index="RING", columns="SITE", values="CLLI", aggfunc=", ".join
    )
    for s, r in zip(x.SITE, x.RING):
        tmp = z.loc[z.index != r, s]
        out.append(", ".join(tmp[tmp.notna()]) or np.nan)
    return pd.Series(out, index=x.index)


df["NeigbourCLLI"] = df.groupby("CIRCUIT", group_keys=False).apply(fn)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    RING     CLLI     CIRCUIT  SITE     NeigbourCLLI
0   N100     M200    Circuit1  M200          M200 23
1   N100     M200    Circuit2  M200              NaN
2   N100     M201    Circuit3  M201              NaN
3   N101  M200 23    Circuit1  M200             M200
4   N101     M300    Circuit1  M300              NaN
5   N101  M304 XK   Circuit11  M304     M304E5, M304
6   N101     M147   Circuit10  M147              NaN
7   N102   M304E5   Circuit11  M304    M304 XK, M304
8   N102     M874  Circuit114  M874              NaN
9   N102     M874  Circuit113  M874              NaN
10  N102     M874  Circuit112  M874              NaN
11  N104     M643    Circuit2  M643              NaN
12  N104     M643  Circuit234  M643              NaN
13  N104     M304   Circuit11  M304  M304 XK, M304E5
```

Comment: Hey @Andrej, thanks for the answer. Yeah this works just fine in case of small df, but in my case I have tried it for 10 minutes an it is still running. That's why I asked if there is a way to avoid .apply with functions and use a more 'pandas' way...

Comment: @user14073111 I've edited the function again and simplified it a little bit (now grouping by `CIRCUIT` and `SITE`)